# What does the +=1 does in this line of code d[i] += 1

Tags: python

I'm really new to programming so sorry for the silly question but can anyone tell me what the (+= 1) represent and what is the purpose of that in the (d[i] += 1) please (i'm so confused because the input is going to be a string and we are( += ) a number)

```
word1 = input("Enter your first word: ")
word2 = input("Enter your second word: ")
def anagram_checker(word):
    d = {}
    for i in word:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return d

if anagram_checker(word1) == anagram_checker(word2):
    print("These words are anagrams.")
else:
    print("These words are not anagrams.")`
```

Comment: `d[i] += 1` is the same as `d[i] = d[i] + 1`.  It adds 1 to the current value.  Note that `d[i]` is an `int` in the dictionary `d` that corresponds to the letter `i`; it starts at `1` the first time you see that letter, and then increments by 1 each time thereafter.  (Your `anagram_checker` function is basically identical to the built-in `collections.Counter` class.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the number of each character in the word. If `i in d` is true, it means you've already seen `i` at least once, so you add `1` to its current count. Otherwise, this is the *first* time you've seen `i`, so you define `d[i] == 1`.

In practice, you would use `collections.Counter` (a subclass of `dict`) instead of implementing such a counter yourself.

```
from collections import Counter


def anagram_checker(word):
    return Counter(word)
```

For example,

```
>>> Counter("mississippi")
Counter({'i': 4, 's': 4, 'p': 2, 'm': 1})
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, so with that counter it will count the letters in the word and consequently tell me if they are anagrams or not